# Have HTML anchor simulating clicking a different element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="clickVehicleTab();">Vehicle Info</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function clickVehicleTab() {
    $("#vehicle").trigger('click');
  }
</script>
```

The function gets executed, however the jQuery to click the object doesn't seem to be executing successfully. What am I missing?

EDIT:

It appears the bind on the `#vehicle` object is a problem. It looks like this:

```
$('#jsddm > #vehicle').bind('click', openVehicleMenu);  //vehicle menu click event
```

So the `#vehicle` can't be programattically clicked directly the way I'm trying.

Comment: You are probaby missing the element with ID vehicle.

Comment: What do you expect `$("#vehicle").trigger('click');` to do? You need to provide enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I trigger a click event on this bind?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314718/how-do-i-trigger-a-click-event-on-this-bind)

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be adding an id to the link and using this to listen to the trigger event. Then when this is entered trigger the click-event on the element with the id "vehicle"

```
<a href="#" id="url">Vehicle Info</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#url").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('TEST: clickVehicleTab entered...');
        $("#vehicle").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

---

If the binding is done programatically why don't you just use:

```
openVehicleMenu();
```

instead of

```
$("#vehicle").trigger('click');
```

Comment: What that is possibly true, it doesn't address the problem the question is asking about.

Comment: What does the `id` field do exactly in the anchor declaration?

Comment: the id is used in the jquery to define which click should be handled. $('#url").click