# How do I trigger a click event on this bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a bind like this:

```
$('#jsddm > #vehicle').bind('click', openVehicleMenu);  //vehicle menu click event
```

and I want to do this:

```
 $('#vehicle').trigger('click');
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Doesn't work, openVehicleMenu() never gets executed.

Comment: That is correct, as @DanLee says. You must have something else wrong.

Comment: See this fiddle, I mocked it out and it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/gph78/. As Liam stated something else must've gone wrong

Comment: OK, Ill have to keep looking. thanks.

Comment: Declare the openVehicleMenu function, outside the jQuery scope. (i.e) `$(document).ready(function () {

        });

        (function ($) {

        })(jQuery);' don't use that function inside these scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as advertised, see

```html
<ul id="jsddm">
    <li id="vehicle">Vehicle</li>
</ul>
```

```js
function openVehicleMenu() {
    console.log('openVehicleMenu');
}

$('#jsddm > #vehicle').bind('click', openVehicleMenu);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkKkm/)

What might be the problem though, if you have an `a` element inside the `li`

```html
<ul id="jsddm">
    <li><a id="vehicle" href="#">Vehicle</a></li>
</ul>
```

you must modify the selector to, e.g.

```js
$('#jsddm #vehicle').bind('click', openVehicleMenu);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkKkm/1/)

With `#jsddm > #vehicle`, the `vehicle` element must be a direct child of `jsddm`. If `vehicle` is some further descendant of `jsddm`, this won't work. You must omit the [`>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching) child selector or be more specific, like `#jsddm li #vehicle`, for example.

Since the selector addresses an `id`, which should be unique, you can just take that for the selector, of course. This avoids these kind of problems altogether

```js
$('#vehicle').bind('click', openVehicleMenu);
```